# Filtrar nombres con C#

Tags: c#

Estoy utilizando arreglos y quería saber qué puedo hacer para poder filtrar nombres, como por ejemplo: escribo el nombre del producto por consola "Retrovisores de Mazda" y que cuando busque por "Mazda" me diga que se encontraron los productos de esa marca.

Aquí se escriben los datos por la consola

```
void Insertar()
        {
          if (ContarRegistros() == Produ.Length)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("No hay espacio...");
          }
          else
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < Produ.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Vaciode(i))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el producto n. " + i);
                    string producto = Console.ReadLine();
                    Produ[i] = producto;
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el precio de " + Produ[i]);
                    double precio = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    Precios[i] = precio;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    }

void flitrar(){
string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string s2 = "fox";
bool b = s1.Contains(s2);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is in the string '{1}': {2}", s2, s1, b);
if (b) 
    {
    int index = s1.IndexOf(s2);
    if (index >= 0)
        Console.WriteLine("'{0} begins at character position {1}", s2, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Y estaba buscando en páginas oficiales pero solo hay estos.

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Ese ejemplo es exactamente lo que tenes que hacer.. que es lo que no entendiste de ese codigo?

Comment: buenas @gbianchi lo que quiero hacer es poder filtrar por el nombre del producto ,ya cree una clase para buscar pero no le encuentro forma de poder filtra el nombre porque el mensaje los escribo por consola y poder buscar por la letra que tenga el mensaje. y espero que puedes haber entendido lo que quiero decir gracias

Comment: Pero eso exactamante hace el codgio que esta escrito ahi...

Comment: pero quiero hacer lo que escriba por consola pueda buscar creando un "void" para poder buscar la letra o por el nombre ingresando por consola. Ejemplo: Escribe el producto: Frasco de Mayonesa, sachet de mayonesa         datos ingresados con éxito.                                                                    elija la opción filtrar el nombre del producto:                                               "mayonesa"                                                                                                se encontraron dos productos con el nombre "mayonesa" y que me diga los nombres

Comment: Hola Juan, si alguna respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo haber entendido lo que requieres. El segundo Void de flirtrar necesitas adaptarlo a que filtre lo que contengas en el arreglo Produ, ya que actualmente solo está filtrando un string constante.

Mi propuesta es modificar el void flirtrar para que utilice tu arreglo Produ.
Como no adjuntaste el codigo completo para hacer una versión reproducible de tu problema, genere algunas variables para poder mostrarte el posible funcionamiento de lo que buscas.

```
string[] Produ = new string[5]; -->Inicializo el arreglo con capacidad de 5 elementos
Produ[0] = "Mayonesa Mckormick";
Produ[1] = "Salsa Ketchup"; -->Agrego 2 productos al arreglo
flitrar(); -->Mando a llamar el metodo

void flitrar()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Escribe la palabra a filtrar");
  string s2 = Console.ReadLine(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < Produ.Length; i++)
    {
      if (Produ[i] != null) -->Para no causar error si el arreglo no está lleno de elementos
      {
        string s1 = Produ[i];
        bool b = s1.Contains(s2);
        if (b)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("La palabra '{0}' se encontró en el producto: '{1}': {2}", s2, s1, b);
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de **Linq**, de esta forma ahorrarás código, siguiendo tu lógica podría quedar así:

```
void Filtrar()
{
   string s2 = Console.ReadLine();
   var existe = Produ.Any(p => p.Contains(s2));

   if(existe)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("El producto se encontró");
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("El producto no se encontró");
   }
}
```

Aquí se usa el **método Any** de **Linq** el cual devuelve **true** o **false**, atendiendo a si existe al menos un producto en el arreglo de productos que cumple la condición especificada, de encontrarse el producto se muestra el correspondiente mensaje en pantalla.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```